# Determine intent filters associated with a service

Tags: android, android-service

We removed an SDK from our Android app (all class and method references) and pushed it to the play store, but forgot to remove the declaration for it from the manifest:

```
    <service android:name="com.radiumone.emitter.location.LocationService"/>
```

Today we have one crash through Crittercism that didn't happen in regression testing in which an attempt is made to load this service.  My research suggests the only way this could happen is if the service is exported by default, and that can only happen if the service contains intent-filters.  Is this true, and if so, how do I find the intent-filters associated with a service?  I can't find any contained in my AndroidManifest.xml; where else should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this true

In an unmodified application, yes.

> how do I find the intent-filters associated with a service?

They would be child elements of the `<service>` element in your manifest. If your element is as it is shown in the question, you have no `<intent-filter>` elements, and your service is not exported.

> I can't find any contained in my AndroidManifest.xml; where else should I look?

There is no place else to look.

> Today we have one crash through Crittercism that didn't happen in regression testing in which an attempt is made to load this service.

You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide more details about the crash, to try to get our help in confirming your belief that somebody else is attempting to start or bind to your service. Perhaps you are misinterpreting the results.